# How to suppress warning message showing unable to register ocx in Installshield?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2009

In want to suppress warning message generated while installing application through Installshield Environment.

Is there some kind of CONDITION that can be put in the Installshield Application builder while creating Installation file ?

Comment: What project type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities and I'm not sure which your scenario is. But just make sure you have turned off COM Extract at Build for the component (if you see the warning at build), and marked it not Self-Registering (if you see the warning during installation).

I think at least the latter is a right-click file property in Express editions instead of an option on the component grid (as there is no component grid in Express editions).